# ElasticSearch catenate_words -- only keep concatenated value

Tags: elasticsearch, string-concatenation

Following examples here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-graph-tokenfilter.html

Specifically the catenate_words option.

I would like to use this to concatenate words that I can then use in a phrase query before and after the concatenated word, but the word parts prevent this.

For example, their example is this:
super-duper-xl → [ superduperxl, super, duper, xl ]

Now if my actual phrase was "what a great super-duper-xl" that would turn into a sequence:

[what,a,great,superduperxl,super,duper,xl]

That matches the phrase "great superduperxl" which is fine.

However, if the phrase was "the super-duper-xl emerged" the sequence would be:

[the,superduperxl,super,duper,xl,emerged]

This does *not* phrase match "superduperxl emerged", however it *would* if the part tokens (super,duper,xl) were not emitted.

Is there any way I can concatenate words keeping only the concatenated word and filtering out the word parts?

Answer (score 0):

[Pattern replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) character filter can be used here.

"-" is replaced with "" to  generate tokens

**Query**

```
PUT my-index1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "remove_hyphen_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "remove_hyphen_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "remove_hyphen_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "-",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "remove_hyphen_analyzer"
      }
       
    }
  }
}
```

```
POST my-index1/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "remove_hyphen_analyzer",
  "text": "the super-duper-xl emerged"
}
```

**Result**

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "the",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "superduperxl",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "emerged",
      "start_offset" : 19,
      "end_offset" : 26,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks - can I use this after the word_delimiter_graph filter (without catenation) to remove/replace characters after the words have been split down? I still want basic splitting on word/number boundaries for examples.

Comment: @aaa90210  yes you can ex."remove_hyphen_analyzer": {  "tokenizer": "standard",  "char_filter": [
            "remove_hyphen_filter"     ],         "filter":"word_delimiter_graph"
        }